# PHP: Google Service autoloader not finding classes

Tags: php, composer-php, google-client

I have the following in my composer.json (unrelated packages not shown):

```
"require": {
    "googleads/googleads-php-lib": "^39.0",
    "google/apiclient": "2.7.2",
    "google/cloud-storage": "^1.23",
    "googleads/google-ads-php": "^14.0",
    "phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0.31"
}
```

I have confirmed that the vender/autoload.php is being invoked. But when I use this code:

```
    $default_scope_set = array(
                                Google\Service\Plus::PLUS_LOGIN,
                                Google\Service\Plus::PLUS_ME,
                                Google\Service\Plus::USERINFO_EMAIL,
                              );
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Class 'Google\Service\Plus' not found in /home/httpd/idxv3/lib/GoogleAuthenticator.php:38
```

I just cannot figure out where I went wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: try `\Google\Service\Plus::PLUS_LOGIN` instead of `Google\Service\Plus::PLUS_LOGIN`

Comment: Please share more details. Why do you use such an outdated version of `google/apiclient`? Also, are you sure you still want to use anything related to Google+ which is closed since years?

Comment: This is what is in composer:  "google/apiclient": "2.7.2". I didn't realize it was that old, I have just upgraded to 2.12.1. As to the Google+, I figured out Friday that needed changing - I'm picking this up some time after it was originally written, we're in the process of upgrading PHP, triggering all sorts of things. I'm going to switch from PLUS to something more current.

Comment: ok, so I updated to apiclient 2.12.1, now I'm getting this error again: "Class 'Google_Service' not found in /home/httpd/idxv3/vendor/google/apiclient-services/autoload.php". Well, it's a warning, but it flashes up on our web pages, which is obviously unacceptable. This is what I was trying to get rid of in the first place.

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve that? That class does not exist anymore under this name, as v2.8.0 added namespaces replacing the underscore notation. Also, v2.12.1 is also outdated, as v2.12.2 has been released two weeks ago and v2.12.3 is just some hours old - why not use the latest version available?

Comment: I have resolved most everything at this point. Changed away from the Plus stuff that my predecessor(s) were using, updated all references to namespaced stuff.. as to the version of api-client, well I went to this page: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client  and it says 2.12.1. The constant churn of versions is rather maddening, but using something that is hours old is not attractive - I have 10s of thousands of customers to support, I feel no need to be on the bleeding edge. But I am fixed up now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, several changes have fixed my issues:

Moved away from Google+ references left over from this code's introduction years ago.

Changed underscore references to use namespaces

Upgraded old api-client to 2.12.1. I understand that there are 2 newer versions, but the google doc page for api-client is using 2.12.1, so I'll stick to that for now. My problems are resolved.